# Translating old animation code to new iOS4 block technique

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-animation, objective-c-blocks

I am trying to learn animation with a 2009 book and to my understanding the preferred method for animating in iOS4 is using blocks. The book I am reading uses the old method and I've been trying to translate it to the new method with minimal success.

What the book says:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:animationTimer];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(lastAnimationZero)];

//animations

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

My (apparently fail) translation:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:animationTimer
                    options: (UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | 
                              UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut)
                 animations: ^
                 {
                     animation
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished)
                 {
                     lastAnimation = 0;
                 }];
```

Everytime I run it I (using the block method) get "Program received signal: "SIGABRT" and the console shows

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+    
[UIView animateWithDuration:options:animations:completion:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x8393b4'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the doc for [UIVIew](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html). There is no such method.
The way you wrote block syntax is ok, just send the right message.

Also, replace 'animation' with the instructions you need, the book won't tell you that, as well as `[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:
 @selector(lastAnimationZero)];` in the old version, is actually the message sended when the animation stops, and shouldn't be directly translated to `lastAnimation = 0;`.

Here is a [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) to the method documentation you probably wanted to use.

```
+(void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
                     delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay
                   options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options
                animations:(void (^)(void))animations
                completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion;
```

Comment: I added that lastAnimationZero part and all it does is actually set lastAnimation to zero so that was meant to be the way it is. I also have animations in there already, just didnt wanna bother taking up space. Now unfortunately, even after i cleaned up my block syntax (cleaned up the completion part) it still gave me the same error. I just don't get it. Do I have to do anything special to enable the block syntax? Import a header file and framework?

Comment: No header or framework to include, the block syntax comes up with ios4. Try reading a bit of [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html) about blocks. As I said the exception occurs because no such methods is defined in `UIView`.

Comment: Ahh silly me. For some reason I thought I could exclude any of the following blocks so I skipped delay since I had no need for it. I simply put delay: 0.0 and it worked like a charm. Thanks very much.